# Redux Form - FieldsArray - fields is empty, length is 0

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I tried to follow [FieldArray](http://redux-form.com/7.0.3/examples/fieldArrays/) example but I got fields length zero in renderEmployees - nothing is rendered.

What can be the cause?

[image]

```
class EmployeesContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.employees && this.props.employees.length > 0 &&
                    <FieldArray name="employees" component={renderEmployees}/>
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const renderEmployees = ({ fields }) =>
    <div>
        {fields.map((employee, index) =>
            <div key={index}>
                <Field name={employee.first_name} type="text" component={renderField} className="cell" inputValue={employee.first_name} />
                <Field name={employee.uid} type="text" component={renderField} className="cell" inputValue={employee.uid} />
            </div>
        )}
    </div>;
```

Comment: Could you share the complete code? In the original code, there is a button (in the `renderEmployees`) to modify the content of `fields` when clicked. But I see none in yours.

Comment: True - this is due to the fact I get a list of employees from the BE and I inject  it via initialValues prop - I thought its out of scope of this question, am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem was using a bad form reducer, probably taken from an outdated example:

```
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form/immutable';
```

Its a stupid mistake but I expect a descent error message.
ofcourse the right usage is:

```
import { reducer as reduxFormReducer } from 'redux-form';
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is being rendered, probably, because you have no employees and you don't render the `renderEmployees` component when the employee list is empty.

If you want to have at least 1 employee, in such a way that it will render an empty item, you can pass `initialValues` to the form, passing the array with an empty item.

This is a modified version of the `FieldsArray` example you provided, in which there's 1 initial member.

```
const initialValues = {
  "members": [
    {
      "firstName": "",
      "lastName": "",
      "hobbies": []
    }
  ]
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <div style={{ padding: 15 }}>
      <h2>Field Arrays</h2>
      <FieldArraysForm onSubmit={showResults} initialValues={initialValues} />
      <Values form="fieldArrays" />
    </div>
  </Provider>,
  rootEl,
);
```

Example in CodeSandBox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/DkWkr6Kr5